# Display UIView with a UILabel text mask

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uilabel, calayer

I'm trying to add a `UIView` to a `UILabel`, so that the text is the view's mask, enabling me to do things like animated text backgrounds (much like the slide to unlock label on the lockscreen).

The way I was planning on doing it was using the `mask` property on the view's `layer` to mask it to the shape of the text. However, I cannot find a way to get the `UILabel`'s text shape as a `CALayer`.

Is this even possible? I can only find solutions that override the `-(void)drawRect:` method in the `UILabel`, but this wouldn't give me much flexibility.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817378/ios-uiview-subclass-draw-see-through-text-to-background) help?

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much! I've posted my implementation as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`UIView` added the `maskView` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/maskView) in iOS 8.0. Now, just create a `UILabel` to use as a mask for a `UIView`:

**Objective-C:**

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
label.text = @"Label Text";
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:70];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIView* overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
overlayView.maskView = label;
[self.view addSubview:overlayView];
```

**Swift 2**:

```
let label = UILabel.init(frame: view.frame)
label.text = "Label Text"
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(70)
label.textAlignment = .Center
label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let overlayView = UIView.init(frame: view.frame)
overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
overlayView.maskView = label
    
view.addSubview(overlayView)
```

This creates a crisp `UILabel` with `UIColor.blueColor()` color taken from `overlayView`.

Comment: ohh, that's a nice addition to UIKit! Haven't seen that before. As this is more flexible, I'll mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Also, as the question was originally tagged obj-c, I've added an obj-c version of the code to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

**[mopsled's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35678866/2976878) is more flexible if you building for iOS 8+. However, if you're looking for a pre-iOS 8 answer, here it is.**

---

Thanks to [Linuxios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1008938/linuxios) for pointing me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817378/ios-uiview-subclass-draw-see-through-text-to-background). The key is to use `CATextLayer` instead of `UILabel`.

**Objective-C:**

```
CGRect textRect = {0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 100}; // rect to display the view in

CATextLayer *textMask = [CATextLayer layer];
textMask.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale; // sets the layer's scale to the main screen scale
textMask.frame = (CGRect){CGPointZero, textRect.size};
textMask.foregroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor; // an opaque color so that the mask covers the text
textMask.string = @"Text Mask"; // your text here
textMask.font = (__bridge CFTypeRef _Nullable)([UIFont systemFontOfSize:30]); // your font here
textMask.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter; // centered text

UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:textRect];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
view.layer.mask = textMask; // mask the view to the textMask
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

**Swift:**

```
let textRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 100) // rect to display the view in

let textMask = CATextLayer()
textMask.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale // sets the layer's scale to the main screen scale
textMask.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: textRect.size)
textMask.foregroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor // an opaque color so that the mask covers the text
textMask.string = "Text Mask" // your text here
textMask.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30) // your font here
textMask.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter // centered text

let bgView = UIView(frame: textRect)
bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
bgView.layer.mask = textMask // mask the view to the textMask
view.addSubview(bgView)
```

Comment: @JohnnyRockex yes, sorry! I did this yonks ago, and forgot to set the `contentsScale` of the `CATextLayer`, so it would have come out pretty horrible on a 2x or 3x display. I have corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

I create the custom maskLabel.

Check the answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47105664/7371852

This is the result.
[image]