# How to set a Image as text background in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, uitextview

[image]

I want to set any image as background to my text content as in the image here. I'll have an image when I set it as background to text. It should be applied as the e.g. image here. Also need to maintain the aspect ratio of image. [image]

Comment: It's unclear, but you mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671245/display-uiview-with-a-uilabel-text-mask ?