# Setting text color to clearColor in an iOS 8 Today widget such that it shows the colors behind the Today Screen

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-today-widget

If you notice carefully, the system drawn separators for the calendar Today extension are completely transparent and show the colors behind the Today pull-down View.

And I also see some third party widgets making their text transparent this way. The fantastical widget seems to do this for the events below the calendar view.

Setting text to clearColor does not help, the text just vanishes.

Does anyone know what the trick here is?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing… so far `UIVibrancyEffect` seems to be the way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390446/how-to-replicate-the-blurred-text-in-notification-center-ios-8 and WWDC2014 session 221.

Comment: @richarddas Thanks! I haven't tried it, but certainly looks like the solution