# Vibrancy Effect in Today Extension / Widget in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, today-extension

I would like to add a vibrancy effect to everything visible in the today extension. I found a solution for Objc, but I am not sure how to translate it correctly to Swift.

[How to replicate the blurred text in Notification Center (iOS 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390446/how-to-replicate-the-blurred-text-in-notification-center-ios-8)

My code so far:

```
func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)!) {

    self.preferredContentSize = self.tableView.contentSize
    var effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIVibrancyEffect.notificationCenterVibrancyEffect())
    effectView.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view = effectView
    self.view.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

I have a button with text in the today extension, when I use my code the button is hidden.