# How to add a UIVisiualEffectView in Today View without blur in Xcode / Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, today-extension, uivisualeffectview

I am trying to add a vibrancy text to the today widget via Interface Builder. Like this: [How to replicate the blurred text in Notification Center (iOS 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390446/how-to-replicate-the-blurred-text-in-notification-center-ios-8)

Vibrany works well, but as you can see the background exists, too:

[image]

I couldn't find a way to disable the blurred dark background of the cells. This is what it should like:

[image]

Here's a picture of the document outline:

[image]

The UIVisualEffectView is supposed to be added to the table cell.

Comment: Can you upload a picture showing the entire notification center. I'm not sure what you're referring to as the *background*.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figured it out. Just needed to drag the inner "Visual Effect View" at the same level as the outer one. Then I deleted the latter one. The outer one represents the blur, while the inner one the vibrancy effect.