# What's suggested approach to create UI similar to this (Attached Image) in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface

I found this UI online, the UI looks amazing,  is there any tips on creating such a thing. It seems a customed UITableView.

Many Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do the cards open up when you tap one?

Comment: yeah, it will give out the item details once tapped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a `UITableView` with a custom background image and what looks like custom layers with masking (for the date and tags).

[Here's](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bentagsview) a library for generating tags, though you could easily just create the layers yourself. There's alot of answers on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817378/ios-uiview-subclass-draw-see-through-text-to-background) one which will explain how to mask text on a layer. The textured look on everything is because the opacity of the layers is not quite 100%.

As for the background images I'm betting the first one doesn't include the background cell and just has the transparent cutout which shows the background. The other cells most likely have the adjacent cell "background" in the background image (since cells don't overlap). Alternating backgrounds are set based on whether the `indexPath.row` is even or not.

The "0/2012" date on the left side looks like a `UILabel` that's been rotated 90 degrees and stroked.

The rest of the cell is just standard text and an image.